# php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] issue

Tags: php, html, css

I'm having an issue when using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`  with css links. 
I have a variable set to:

```
<?php
    $path = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/");
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
?>
```

I am using the $path variable to point to navigation pages include on my page that contain css file links. For example in `index.php`:

```
<?php
    include ($path . "includes/_navTop.php");
?>
```

The css links in the `_navTop.php` page is:

```
<?php
    echo '<link href="' . $path . 'includes/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">';
?>
```

When I test the page in a Firefox and Chrome, I get 404 not found errors in the developer console. The path shows as:

```
http://www.example.com/data/9/3/5/155/3657318/user/4068338/htdocs/includes/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

When using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, is it suppose to insert the site address also?

Comment: You can't use the same variable for a file system path and a URL. They're entirely different document trees.

Comment: Should be noted that using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` can be spoofed, and can represent a security risk depending on how it's used. You should just define your URL base somewhere in your front controller. something like `define('BASE_URL', 'http://example.com/');`. Then you can use `BASE_URL` anywhere you want.

Answer (score 1):

In `_navTop.php` you're using `$path` in your href, which is built earlier on from `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`: a server-side local address (like /home/user/www).  I think what you might be trying to do would involve using 'HTTP_HOST', e.g.

```
$base = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
echo '<link href="' . $base . 'includes/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">';
```

However, I think writing the link's href beginning at `include/...` should also work as most browsers resolve the base address (when not given) to be the domain itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of placing a project in a subfolder (from your document root here a folder called my-project), and using an auto-prepend script (a script that is run before your php scripts) added through apache configuration (.htaccess) to define constants that you can use elsewhere.

File Structure from (/var/www/my-project):

```
.
|-- __bootstrap.php
|-- foo
|   `-- bar.php
|-- .htaccess
|-- qux.php
`-- static
    `-- main.css
```

./.htaccess

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /var/www/my-project/__bootstrap.php
```

./__bootstrap.php

```
<?php
define('LOCAL_BASE', __DIR__);
define('PUBLIC_BASE', str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', __DIR__));
```

./foo/bar.php

```
<?php

var_dump(LOCAL_BASE);
var_dump(PUBLIC_BASE);
```

Output:

```
string '/var/www/my-project' (length=29)
string '/my-project' (length=17)
```

./qux.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= PUBLIC_BASE ?>/static/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

However for Php includes, I'd be more inclined to put something in my include path.  And use a namespace (a sub folder in your includes folder) to group them.

```
set_include_path('/path/to/project/includes');
```

And in Php files you can then do, wherever you are in the file hierarchy:

```
include 'my-project/common.php';
```

The important point here is that there is a difference between local file paths and public paths.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know the real path to your project on the server.  You only need to specify the folder relative to DOCUMENT_ROOT.  The following will do the trick:

```
<?php
echo '<link href="/includes/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">';
?>
```

This path is used by the client's browser to request the resource from the WEB server and this all it needs to know.
Providing the full actual path is actually a security risk.